# Where is a starting place to learn how to encrypt a password in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

Im interested in learning about sending an encrypted password from a form in php to a mysql database. What would be a good starting point for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [Basic security, PHP mySQl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701954/basic-security-php-mysql)

And here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

And remember hashing is what you're after, not encryption. Hashing is one way, encryption is reversible (decypting it).

Comment: Well the issue is, ive used md5 and then sent it to a database (as a part of a register process)..but then trying to sign in, the user would need to use the md5 hash... or in my login script, would i send a md5 version of the password variable to the database?

Comment: Don't use md5, it's not secure for passwords. I would recommend SHA-512. What you would do is take the password they specified, and then hash it. Compare the values they entered (username), and the calculated hash and search for a row in the db. If it's found, you can do additional checks and then log them in. If no rows are found, their username and/or password is invalid, and can be displayed as such. Does that make sense?

Comment: Doesn't really make sense but thats because Im new to all this. But ill look into it... on a login scrypt then, would i turn what they enter as their password and hash it with SHA 512 and then try to find that in the database? Sorry I don't quiet have all the vocabulary down yet, hope you get what im saying.

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere! Yup, that's exactly it. So you take the password, hash it, then look in the database for that hashed password AND the username. If nothin' is returned, then the info is invalid.

Comment: Where as if i did it md5 it wouldnt make the connection between the password and the username or would it still? Why isnt md5 secure?

Comment: It'd make the connection since you're storing the password already hashed, and you're comparing two like things. It's really complicated stuff, if you want to read about it, Wikipedia has a great article as to why it isn't secure - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security the short answer is don't use it for storing passwords.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about MySQL but SQLite encryption and reverse on the fly (http://sqlite.biz/index.php?area=Main&page=DBcTutorial) this is a pear library so you can get it at http://pear.php.net and use the same mechanism with MySQL.